# why does my getDownloadurl() return null?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

i am using flutter and firebase so im trying to display the images i upload on the same app but this url is null everytime i upload ... most of the solutions i find are related to android  and hardly applicable to flutter....

```
filePath = 'Images/$order.png';
    storageUploadTask = storage.ref().child(filePath).putFile(finalImage);
    storageUploadTask.onComplete.then((value) {
      if (value.error == null) {
        storageTaskSnapshot = value;
        storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadUrl) {
          photoUrl = downloadUrl.toString();
        }).catchError((onError) {
          print('I error from the upload.');
        });
      }
    });

    await globals.firestore.collection('AdminMessage').add({
      'text': captionController == null
          ? 'Image Uploaded'
          : captionController.value,
      'order': order,
      'time': time,
      'from': globals.sitename,
      'isImage': true,
      'imgPath': photoUrl,
    });
    captionController = null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `getDownloadURL()` is an asynchronous call. Any code that needs the result from that call, needs to be inside the callback. So:

```
filePath = 'Images/$order.png';
storageUploadTask = storage.ref().child(filePath).putFile(finalImage);
storageUploadTask.onComplete.then((value) {
  if (value.error == null) {
    storageTaskSnapshot = value;
    storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadUrl) {
      photoUrl = downloadUrl.toString();

      await globals.firestore.collection('AdminMessage').add({
        'text': captionController == null
            ? 'Image Uploaded'
            : captionController.value,
        'order': order,
        'time': time,
        'from': globals.sitename,
        'isImage': true,
        'imgPath': photoUrl,
      });
      captionController = null;
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print('I error from the upload.');
    });
  }
});
```

---

Alternatively, since you're already using `await` anyway, you can also just `await` the `onComplete` and `getDownloadURL` calls:

```
filePath = 'Images/$order.png';
storageUploadTask = storage.ref().child(filePath).putFile(finalImage);
let value = await storageUploadTask.onComplete;
if (value.error == null) {
  storageTaskSnapshot = value;
  let downloadUrl = storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  photoUrl = await downloadUrl.toString();

  await globals.firestore.collection('AdminMessage').add({
    'text': captionController == null
        ? 'Image Uploaded'
        : captionController.value,
    'order': order,
    'time': time,
    'from': globals.sitename,
    'isImage': true,
    'imgPath': photoUrl,
  });
  captionController = null;
}
```